# How to transform repeating numbered columns in Pandas to singular, non-numbered columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Apologies for the (potentially) poor title, but I have a hard time understanding how to describe this myself. I have a dataset that, when read into a pandas dataframe, has roughly the following shape:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
df_all = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 6), columns=["0_X", "0_Y", "1_X", "1_Y", "2_X", "2_Y"])
  0_X       0_Y       1_X       1_Y       2_X       2_Y
0 1.470289  0.588573  1.303684  1.374806  1.025082  0.316623
1 0.426527  2.036558  0.100993  2.485025  0.350100  0.603069
```

Each pair of columns with the same number represent the (X, Y) positions for an object at a given timestamp. Each row represents a new timestamp. What I would like to do is transform this dataframe into something like this:

```
   Time   ObjectId   X         Y 
0  0      0          1.470289  0.588573  
1  0      1          1.303684  1.374806  
2  0      2          1.025082  0.316623
3  1      0          0.426527  2.036558  
4  1      1          0.100993  2.485025  
5  1      2          0.350100  0.603069
```

Now, I know I can extract the relevant information from the column **names** and repeat it like so:

```
obj_ids = []
for each_column in list(df_all.columns):
  obj_id = each_column.split("_")[0]
  if obj_id not in obj_ids:
    obj_ids.append(obj_id)

df_all_rotated = pd.DataFrame()
df_all_rotated["ObjectID"] = obj_ids 
df_all_rotated = pd.concat([df_all_rotated ] * len(df_all.index), ignore_index=True)
```

This produces something close to the first part of what I want:

```
      ObjectId   
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     0
4     1
5     2
```

But unfortunately, I get stuck when thinking how to move the (X,Y) points to their proper positions in the dataframe. I know there are ways of doing this by looping over the entirety of the dataframe and setting each dataframe cell to its respective value, but those seem inefficient especially considering that the datasets will be in the MBs of information, and I have bad (runtime) experiences with using "C-like" looping methods in Pandas.

The easy answer is "change the dataset" but sadly I do not control how that is generated :(

Any help is appreciated! My apologies if this is a repost.

Comment: Is it safe to assume there will be the same number of X's and Ys ? I feel I've seen a similar issue sometime ago, maybe with a little search you can find it, as I can find it atm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We first convert the column index into a [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples) and then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas.DataFrame.stack) the first level to columns. Finally we [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the new columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 6), columns=["0_X", "0_Y", "1_X", "1_Y", "2_X", "2_Y"])

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([c.split('_') for c in df.columns])
df.stack(0).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0': 'Time', 'level_1': 'ObjectId'})
   Time ObjectId         X         Y
0     0        0  0.862742 -1.642483
1     0        1  0.786022 -0.661986
2     0        2  0.044130  1.054564
3     1        0 -1.415127 -1.197613
4     1        1  0.530939  1.238403
5     1        2  0.495760  0.101748
```

---

**Edit**:
As commented by sammywemmy below you can simplify the first line to

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
```

Comment: pandas string split with expand set to True will give you a multiindex. Takes away the need to iterate through the columns and call on pd.multiindex

Comment: @sammywemmy: Thanks a lot, I didn't know that. Included it into the answer.

Comment: This works well! Thanks so much, I appreciate it. Marked as answered. Just one small note for anyone else coming across this question and that's that df.stack() returns a  dataframe, so you'll need to capture the updated dataframe by saying something like df = df.stack

Answer (score 1):

Here is `wide_to_long`

```
df_all.columns=df_all.columns.str.split('_').map(lambda x : ''.join(x[::-1]))

df=pd.wide_to_long(df_all.rename_axis('Time').reset_index(),['X','Y'],i='Time',j='ObjectId',suffix='\\w+').reset_index()
df
Out[89]: 
   Time  ObjectId         X         Y
0     0         0 -0.121748  0.146057
1     1         0  1.883143  0.088054
2     0         1  0.841091 -1.034432
3     1         1  0.444028 -0.711991
4     0         2 -0.677578  1.401241
5     1         2 -0.424676 -0.933622
```

Comment: I was banging my head trying to make it work, thank you! This is the best answer imo